# Calculate hours difference in datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a series of datetime values. I want to select records with a difference of 2 or more hours between them.

```
2010-02-11 08:55:00.000
2010-02-11 10:45:00.000
2010-02-11 10:55:00.000
2010-02-11 12:55:00.000
2010-02-11 14:52:00.000
2010-02-11 16:55:00.000
2010-02-11 17:55:00.000
2010-02-11 23:55:00.000
2010-02-12 00:55:00.000
2010-02-12 02:55:00.000
```

Expected (The next date compared is with the last date that qualified for the 2 hr difference):

```
2010-02-11 08:55:00.000
2010-02-11 10:55:00.000
2010-02-11 12:55:00.000
2010-02-11 16:55:00.000
2010-02-11 23:55:00.000
2010-02-12 02:55:00.000
```

I am using SQL 2005 or 2008

Comment: Can you give us more context? Why two hours? what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: apparently the client has many records in a day, so to reduce the records they have decided to keep a diff of 2 hrs..works for them i guess.

Comment: Are you looking for all the dates with an interval of atleast 2 hours?

Comment: Why is 2010-02-11 10:45:00.000 -> 2010-02-11 12:55:00.000 not output?

Answer (score 1):

Use the DATEDIFF function e.g.

```
 select datediff(mi,Date1, IsNull(Date2, Date1)) from Table1
```

please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: that does not produce the expected output